# Drawing from a node in 2 different directions using inline node

Tags: tikz-pgf

In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/445674/drawing-from-a-node-in-2-different-directions/445680#445680), I supplied a code to take an external node as a reference and I`ve got satisfying answers.

Using these answers to draw from an inline node I used the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (5,0);
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (0,4.);
\draw [thick, violet, dotted] (4,3) node (oo){} node [xshift=0cm, yshift=0cm] {oo} (oo.center-|0,0) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=0cm] {y} -| (oo.center|-0,0) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=0cm] {x};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

to get

[image]

When omitting naming the starting point node in this code

```
    \draw [thick, violet, dotted] (4,3) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=0cm] {o} |- (0,0) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=0cm] {y} -| (0,0) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=0cm] {x};
```

I got

[image]

How can this be fixed?

Here is the full code I use:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (5,0);
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (0,4.);
\draw [thick, violet, dotted] (4,3) node (oo){} node [xshift=0cm, yshift=0cm] {oo} (oo.center-|0,0) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=0cm] {y} -| (oo.center|-0,0) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=0cm] {x};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (5,0);
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (0,4.);
\draw [thick, violet, dotted] (4,3) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=0cm] {o} |- (0,0) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=0cm] {y} -| (0,0) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=0cm] {x};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: now you should already know for mwe. please provide it.

Comment: I updated my question with the full codes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code:

```
\draw[thick,violet,dotted](4,3)node[xshift=0cm, yshift=0cm]{o}|-(0,0) node[xshift=0cm, yshift=0cm]{y}-|(0,0)node[xshift=0cm, yshift=0cm]{x}
```

Is equivalent without nodes to:

```
\draw[draw_styles]
(4.3) %Initial path coordinate
    -|(0,0) % (4.3) Linked to (0,0) using cornered link (-|)
    -|(0,0); % (0.0) Linked to (0,0)
```

In the pevious code you:

```
\draw(4,3)node (oo){} node [xshift=0cm, yshift=0cm] {oo} (oo.center-|0,0) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=0cm] {y} -| (oo.center|-0,0) node [xshift=0cm, yshift=0cm] {x};
```

And its equvalent code without nodes is:

```
\draw[draw_styles]
(4.3) %Initial path coordinate <nothing is drawn, but you use to put a text named node>
(4.3 -| 0,0) % That gives a new coordinate (4,0) <4.3 is the equivalent of node_name.center.>
        -|(0,0 |- 4.3); % (4,0) Linked to (0,3) using cornered link (-|)
```

Both codes does not draw the respective lines from (4.3) point; the code that could do this is using edge and coordinate to not rewrite the coordinate when the intersection points using `(A-|B)` or `(A|-B)` are calculated.

The initial coordinate has a text node with the text `{o}`, but also has a `label` in position 45 degrees then the coordinate is asigned to `P` constant symbol, then two edges are drawn to points `(P -| 0,0)` and `(P |- 0,0)`; the code to place text nodes in the lines by edge, is written between edge and the coordinate; but the position from 0 to 1 must be specified, being the extreme limits of the line, in the same way the text nodes can contain labels.

RESULT:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        font=\sffamily,
        >={Stealth[inset=0pt,length=6pt]},
        ]
    \draw [thick,->](0,0) -- (5,0);
    \draw [thick,->](0,0) -- (0,4.);
    %Option using edge
    \draw [thick, violet, dotted] (4,3) node[label=45:o,inner sep=-3pt]{o} coordinate (P)
        edge  node[pos=1,label=180:y,inner sep=-3pt]{y} (P -| 0,0) 
        edge node[pos=1,label=-90:x,inner sep=-3pt]{x}  (P |- 0,0) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and explanation. It gives me what I want. Just one comment, using label=180:y and {y} prints it twice. I will omit one of them.

Comment: Just one more comment please. If I use many \drawing commands in the same tikzpicture, could they all have the same coordinate (P) or should each one have a different name?

Comment: The constant assignments are even kept out of the tikzpicture environment, if you then write `\draw (P)-(0,0)` in another tikz picture environment in another frame; a line will be drawn from the same direction towards the origin, if you make another diferent drawing, it could change if you re asingn another value and change forward.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest to use two draw commands instead of one and the command `\currentcoordinate` from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132926/110998).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
% Taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132926/110998
\makeatletter
\newcommand\currentcoordinate{\the\tikz@lastxsaved,\the\tikz@lastysaved}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (5,0);
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (0,4.);
\draw [thick, violet, dotted] (4,3) node {o} -- (\currentcoordinate-|0,0) node {y};
\draw [thick, violet, dotted] (4,3) -- (\currentcoordinate|-0,0) node {x};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it gives me the same result as my first code which is more simple using naming the node. What I want, if possible, is using the (0,0) method which does not need to define other coordinates than that of the node, without naming the node.

Answer (score 5):

What you want can be achieved by using the `calc` library in combination with the `let` command.

You can use `let \p1 = (<coordinate>) in` somewhere in your path definition, to let `\p1` correspond to that coordinate everywhere in the path definition. Additionally you can use the `x` and `y` coordinates as `\x1` and `\y1` which make the `-|` and `|-` notation unnecessary.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (5,0);
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (0,4.);
\draw [thick, orange,dotted] let \p1 = (4,3) in {
    (\p1) -- node[above]{x} (0,\y1) 
    (\p1) -- node[right]{y} (\x1,0)
    (\p1) node[above right]{oo}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

The following example is to show that it works by only changing the coordinates for `\p1`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\foreach \t in {0,10,...,359}{
\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (5,0);
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (0,4.);
\draw [thick, orange,dotted] let \p1 = ({3+cos(\t)},{2+sin(\t)}) in {
    (\p1) -- node[above]{x} (0,\y1) 
    (\p1) -- node[right]{y} (\x1,0)
    (\p1) node[above right]{oo}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
}
\end{document}
```

Which results in

[image]

Let me conclude by saying that for this simple case the `let` command is probably overkill, but I cannot guess what you will use it for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it gives me the same result as my first code which is more simple using naming the node. What I want, if possible, is using the (0,0) method which does not need to define other coordinates than that of the node, without naming the node.

Comment: Thank you, but it uses two \draw commands. Can it be done using one \draw command.

Comment: Thank you. It is similar to my first method (with naming the node). What I want is using this method without naming the node.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and answers. In my original code, my drawing is much more complicated with many nodes; and I want to avoid naming too many nodes. I think what I want is not possible.

Comment: The answer of J Leon V. answers my question and gives me what I want. Thank you all for your answers and comments.

Comment: Thank you, but this solution does not name the node, which I want to do; and it is very simple.

Comment: Just one more comment please. If I use many \drawing commands in the same tikzpicture, could they all have the same node name (P1) or should each one have a different name? Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81566/discussion-between-max-snippe-and-hany).